# Can't run flutter app on physical Apple devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter, sigabrt

I have a perfectly working Xcode (at least for Swift iOS projects), today I tried to install flutter.
I followed the steps from here: [FlutterDev](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos) (every step, so the solution is not here)

I can build and run Flutter projects in terminal on Simulator on iPhones and Android Virtual Devices as well.

Flutter doctor found everything OK.

But I can't run it on any physical Apple device. Tested on 2 MacBook Pros -> deploying to 3 different iPhones.

I got SIGABRT error right after the app tried to launch if I run the from Xcode, and the terminal stuck in installing and launching... if I try to run the app from there.

Terminal

[image: Terminal problem picture]

Xcode

[image: Xcode error picture]

Comment: Is your app trying to connect to the internet in any way?  A lot of times, apple won't let developers do so, unless they've stated which individual devices it's going to be tested on, So you may need to do that.  If not, I'm not entirely certain.

Comment: Thanks for advise. It is not about "my app", it is about any app. If I try to run the "original app" which Flutter create (the counter app) I got the same error. And non of the tried apps using any network.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should just try these steps:

1) flutter clean

2) flutter build ios --release

Then later do this in Xcode MenuBar: Product -> Clean  and then build in Xcode

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I did everything step by step what you said but got the very same error.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16833 have you checked out this link  maybe this can solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, but that issue is about apk-s and android devices and my problem is iOS specific.

Comment: works like a charm. thank you for this answer, helped me save time.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug from Flutter. Instead switch the channel:

```
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
flutter run
```

But remember: The `dev` channel is far ahead of the stable one, it is little less safe. I would recommend you to use it just for running the app on your device. For coding etc. switch back to the `stable` channel:

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```

The bug will be fixed in `v1.15.3`.

Comment: Thank you! First I got iproxy error, but I used the specific sudo command to solve this, but know have the same issue and the physical ios devices still can't run any flutter app. Now I'm trying to upgrade to beta, some comments said that the new beta solved the problem. I hope so...

Answer (score 0):

After I've spent my day troubleshooting the only solution that worked for me is to download xcode beta, the newest 13.4 iOS beta and then everything worked immediately. I opened the existing projects, hit run and opened on my phone without any extra steps.